# android string Comparison problem?

Tags: java, android

friends,

i am facing an issue

when i display **someone's post** in android listview it shows me

**someone\'s post**

i want to remove **\** from string and wrote following code which give me outofmemory error

```
if(val.contains("\\"))
        {
        val=val.replace("", "\\");
        }
```

any one guide me whats the soultion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't replace work the other way round?

```
val = val.replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> [`public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):
>   Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for example, replacing `"aa"` with `"b"` in the string `"aaa"` will result in `"ba"` rather than `"ab"`.

So the error in this particular case is that you've swapped the arguments around.

```
System.out.println(  "a\\b"                    ); // "a\b"
System.out.println(  "a\\b".replace("", "\\")  ); // "\a\\\b\"
System.out.println(  "a\\b".replace("\\", "")  ); // "ab"
```

Note that you don't really need to do an `if/contains` check: if `target` is not found in your string, then no `replacement` will be made.

```
System.out.println("a+b".replace("\\", "")); // "a+b"
```